# The tweet button should use the site's hashtag

Tags: feature-request, twitter

The #stacksecurity hashtag on Twitter is used by a number of our users to identify tweets associated with security.stackexchange content. To promote use of the hashtag and drive visitors back to the main site, questions or answers shared via the "tweet link" button could automatically include this hashtag, or alternatively the "@stacksecurity" user name of our Twitter bot.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's a particular convention of this site; it's easy enough to edit it in when tweeting via the built in support. I am not sure I want to ritualize and indoctrinate something that's not common to all sites.